# Swift 3.0 online tutorial error to type [String]

Tags: ios, swift, gameplay-kit

I am new to programming in general.

I decided to learn through online tutorials and have been following a tutorial on Youtube creating a game of a space like (bootleg galaga).

I checked everything and I am not sure what I am doing wrong or if there is an Xcode update. How can I fix this so I can complete this tutorial?

Code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var starfield:SKEmitterNode!
    var player:SKSpriteNode!

    var scoreLabel:SKLabelNode!
    var score:Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            scoreLabel.text = "Score:\(score)"
        }
    }
    var possibleAliens = ("alien", "alien2", "alien3")
    var gameTimer:Timer!



    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        starfield = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Starfield")
        starfield.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1472)
        starfield.advanceSimulationTime(10)
        self.addChild(starfield)

        starfield.zPosition = -1

        player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shuttle")
        player.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -1*player.size.height/2 - 500)
        self.addChild(player)
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self


        scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Score: 0")
        scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: -300, y: -1*player.size.height/2 + 600)
        scoreLabel.fontName = "AmericanTypewriter-Bold"
        scoreLabel.fontSize = 36
        scoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.white
        score = 0

        self.addChild(scoreLabel)



        gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.75, target: self, selector: #selector(addAlien), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    func addAlien () {

      possibleAliens = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: possibleAliens) as! [String]   
    }
```

Error:

```
  possibleAliens = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: possibleAliens) as! [String]
```

> "Cannot convert value of type '(String, String, String)' to expected argument type '[Any]'

Comment: You need to update your question with how you declared and assigned your `possibleAliens` variable.

Comment: I just did, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you do
 var possibleAliens = ("alien", "alien2", "alien3")

try 
 var possibleAliens = ["alien", "alien2", "alien3"]

Comment: thank you so much!

Can you let me know what is the best way to learn swift?

Comment: that is really hard to follow since Im a beginner in programming. Still learning java in school!